# Detect jsdoc errors and fail commit

Tags: typescript, jsdoc, husky

One of the most common argument of typescript fans is typescript does not allow you to get build when there are errors on compile time. This argument is somewhat true but we can still get type errors by just using jsdoc however since vanilla javascript does not require compilation step we are able to run that code if we do not pay attention to problems pane in vscode for example. I want to be able to detect errors somehow (maybe I can use babel ?) and fail the commit by using husky. I am not quite sure how I can prevent code that does not satisfy type rules specified by jsdoc comments, I am asking for suggestions regarding that.

Comment: Just run `tsc` as a test in husky. It should fail with an non-zero code and stop your commit

Comment: As said tsc works well and provides a lot of TS type extensions (including e.g. recursive types). If you put a tsconfig.json in your project, you can configure type safety lever and VSCode will also use that to detect errors... you need to specify `allowJs`, `checkJs`, and `noEmit` set to `true`... That is my setup and works well...